# How to put output of python code in the gui format?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

[image: This is the backend code(the one with import urllib2)][image: This(the one with import tkinter is the format in which i want my output from my code]Hello, these are my codes. The first one is the format in which I want my output to be for the 2nd code ..
 Sorry to post snapshot of my code ...the main reason is I was unable to upload my code itself ....plz somebody help me

Comment: Not clear what you are really asking.

Comment: -1 for posting screenshots (instead of reading the instructions on how to format code) and a vote to close for not actually asking a question.

Comment: actually i have written two codes. what i want is i want the output of the console to be printed in the gui.

Comment: i tried to edit code before putting it.... i think more than 50 times but still it is saying my indentation is not correct...:(

Comment: 'urls' seems to disappear after your first with statement is done.

Comment: i m trying to post same thing in new question ...with code

Comment: urls is used again in first try block...it is like list buffer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you only need op. in a GUI window instead of console ? create a window ,add a label and button using tkinter(basic GUI programming).
[basic tutorial for GUI prog.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)

```
l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
```

var will be from your backend code

Comment: yes i need my output on gui not on the console ...

Comment: you need to integrate both yur codes .. just put your backend code into a function  and use label to output the variables in the main window